next/image layout shift problem when using fill={true}
I need to achieve a look like this:

My images are stored on 3rd party services (I don't know their width/height), I use fill.
<div className="relative max-h-96">
 <Image src={url} alt="" fill className="!relative object-cover" />
</div>

As I know when I use fill I need to control the sizes using the the parent element. But my images are dynamic, I need them to be their original sizes on my page (only have the max limit max-h-96).
I can't have a fixed sized parent element. When I have no fixed sized parent element it does layout shifting.
Question #1: How can I solve the layout shifting problem when I have inconsistent image heights like this?

What I am planning: Since I have full control over the image uploading process, I can save image width and height data to the database in advance when users do uploading.
<div className="flex max-h-96 items-center justify-center">
 <Image src={url} alt="" width={width} height={height} className="object-cover" />
</div>

Question #2: It makes me feel like this is too far/overdoing, no?

Do you still need to get this resolved? and, my question is that when you said that having the max limit max-h-96, would it mean that all images' max height should be 96px? so, if a image's height is greater than 96, it should be scaled down, and if the image's height is less than 96, it should be displayed as is?

The problem itself is not resolved yet but I chose a different Twitter like loading bar approach for my app. And yes exactly I need something that you have explained. @0xKevin
